# Word/idiom for not only to get restless, worried or scared (oneself) but also to make others worried /scared

Tags: phrase-requests, idiom-requests, proverb-requests

Is there word/idiom hindi expression

> khud bhi (Self also) darna (to get worry or scared) dusre ko bhi darake chodna (infuse tension/scare in others too).

Because of their timid nature not on purpose.

The meaning is

> not only to get restless, worried or scared (oneself) but also to make others worried /scared.

Comment: You could say that her/his anxiety communicated itself (or infected) the others in the room or the office or wherever they are. (This really isn't a single word request and shouldn't be tagged that way.)

Comment: *Incite* instantly springs to mind. Then there are many suitable synonyms for the same: excite, provoke, instigate, inflame, fuel, kindle, ignite, arouse, foment. Such behaviors often occur mindlessly, without much forethought or reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think these are words/expressions that may come closest to what you ask, but with somewhat less emphasis on the "self" aspect:

to be a fearmongerer

to be a scaremongerer

to be a worrymongerer

The word "monger", meaning to spread, sell, peddle, or push something on someone else, can be used. The word can be used on its own or in combination with other nouns as an ending (for example - worrymongerer, worry-mongerer, or worry mongerer). It usually implies that the person already has the attribute being spread (fear, scared, or worry).

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/scaremonger

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/alarmist

Also, it occurs to me that the word "alarmist" also might work as a person who spreads alarm.